# Ubercart : divide the main stock in stocks per type of users

Tags: users, commerce, ubercart

I have a D6 Ubercart site with the following:

- There are different kind of members (Premium Member, Regular Member).
- There is an online shop, using Ubercart with the possibility to define a stock that is automatically updated when people book a ticket.

So far, all the users have access to the same stock : if I have 100 tickets, it is sold regardless the type of the users.

What I want to do is sub-divide the stock such that one role (e.g. Premium Member) has 60 tickets, while another, has the remaining 40. Each role should only see the amount in stock that is available to them.

I couldn't find a way to personalize the stock in Ubercart. is it possible to do such a thing without installing any complementary module?